# How do I get the body of a request from npm's multer if I don't upload a file?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I have a Node server using `express`.

I was originally using `body-parser`, but that doesn't allow for file uploads. So, I switched to `multer` (the easiest integration with `express`). However, in order to get any of the `req` (specifically `req.body`), this is my code:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest : 'uploads/' });

server.all('/example', function (req, res, next) {
    var up = upload.single('photo')
    up(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body); // I can finally access req.body
    });
}
```

The problem with this, is that not all of my routes need to upload a file. Do I need to waste the CPU on calling `upload.single()` for each route in order to get access to the body? `upload.single('')` ends up not uploading any file, but it's still precious time spent on the main thread.

It appears that `upload.single()` waits for the callback, so it may not be as big of a deal as I'm making it, but I don't like calling functions when I don't have to.

Is there a way around calling `upload.single()`, or am I just making a bigger deal out of this than it really is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text-only multipart forms, you could use any of the multer methods, which are `.single()`, `.array()`, `fields()`

For instance using `.array()`

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest : 'uploads/' });

server.all('/example', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

It doesn't really matter which you use, as long as it's invoked without arguments Multer will only parse the text-fields of the form for you, no files

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `.fields()`. I was also doing something wonky (not quite sure what), that made it so I couldn't access `req` if I called `upload.xxx()` within the routing call, so I had that extra logic within the callback instead.

Comment: As per the guide, there is also a [`.none()` method](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) which is specifically for non-upload handling of text fields.

Comment: @AdamReis But if you add .none() and add files in form-data it will throw error.